# Generating PDF in .NET using XSL-FO

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I need to generate a pdf in .NET using XSL-FO. There are no shortage of libraries to do this. What library would you suggest that I use and why?

Answer (score 7):

*This is an old question, I know, but none of the answers to date actually addressed the OP QUESTION.  She asked for options for using XSL-FO, not "how to generate PDF using code?".*

The primary non-commercial answer on the actual question is:

### Apache.org Project's FOP

Formatting Objects Processor.  It takes XSL-FO compliant xsl code and xml and generates PDF files according to the XSL-FO spec.  There are several other commercial options:

- Ibex PDF Creator
- AntennaHouse
- RenderX

If you're looking for an open-source option that WORKS, FOP is it.  The FOP is a Java library natively, but it has been ported to .NET via J# (That has it's own issues there I know) in the [nFOP project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfop/).

Answer (score 4):

I have in the past used the [Ibex PDF generator](http://www.xmlpdf.com/). I was thrown in in a project that already had a license for that, so I had really no other choice. At first I thought it was cumboersome, but eventually I got used to how it works.

I would recommend that you also use some good XML/XSL editor for testing XSL/XPath. 
[XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/) is a good free open source one.

Answer (score 3):

I researched options a couple of years back. Here's the shortlist: iTextSharp, SharpPDF, Report.NET, NFop and Siberix Report Writer.  Ultimately I went with Siberix but I now think iTextSharp would have been the better choice. If it is helpful, you can find out a bit more [here](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2006/12/04/dynamic-pdf-reporting-for-web-applications/).

Answer (score 2):

http://fonet.codeplex.com/

FO.NET is your library

Answer (score 0):

Well i used iText(open source) a couple of times about 2 years ago, but i would not recommend this. The main reason is the lack of documentation and i really dislike the API it just feels outdated setting global variables before calling functions.

What is the reason you need to use XSL-FO? I also used ABC-pdf(commercial) which allows the user to turn HTML pages ( including stylesheets ) to pdf documents, or you can use a simple and documented API.

Comment: I am trying to generate letters for a university. I doubt I can get funding to buy a commercial product, so free solution is a must. As for using XSL-FO, I can use something different. Would you have any suggestions? Using XSL-FO seems to be the standard way of generating pdfs, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use something different, you can try to use PdfSharp + MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel libraries for .NET (see http://www.pdfsharp.net/). Both have MIT license and free to use in commercial projects.

You can install this libraries from one nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc/).

Then, you can define your PDF DOM with `MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document` class and print it with `PdfDocumentRenderer` class. Here is sample code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel;
using MigraDoc.Rendering;

namespace MigraDocTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var document = new Document();

            // initial page setup and declare the styles
            document.DefaultPageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;

            var mainStyle = document.Styles[StyleNames.Normal];
            mainStyle.Font.Name = "Arial";

            const string TitleStyleName = "Title";

            var titleStyle = document.Styles.AddStyle(TitleStyleName, StyleNames.Normal);
            titleStyle.ParagraphFormat.Font.Size = 12;
            titleStyle.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = "0";
            titleStyle.Font.Bold = true;

            // main page section setup
            var section = document.AddSection();
            section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;
            section.PageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
            section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = "15mm";
            section.PageSetup.RightMargin = "15mm";
            section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "12mm";
            section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = "20mm";

            // add content to DOM here
            section.AddParagraph("Hello, world!").Style = TitleStyleName;

            // actually print document to PDF
            var pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(unicode: true) { Document = document };
            pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pdfRenderer.Save(stream, closeStream: false);
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"_output.pdf", stream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that MigraDoc nuget supports .NET Framework 2+, .NETStandard is not supported. So, you need targeting to full .NET Framework to use this libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a pure port of `Apache FOP version 2.8` that runs in `.Net Core`. It's pretty much plug-n-play, so it super easy to use. Check it out:

https://github.com/sorcerdon/FOP.NetCore

Here is the nuget:

[image: NuGet version (FOP.NetCore)]

Since this is a pure port, that means that it can do anything that Apache FOP can do.