# IKVM Apache FOP

Tags: c#, apache, apache-fop, ikvm

I am trying to compile the Apache FOP v1.0 library to a .NET DLL. I followed the instructions in: 
[Using ApacheFOP v1.0 in .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961476/using-apachefop-v1-0-in-net-application)

However when i run the ikvmc command i get a number of warnings (which i can live with), and then an error:

> System.ArgumentException: An Item with the same key has already been added.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to fix this?
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 2):

This is an ikvm regression in the development snapshot caused by the unnecessary -reference:IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll. If you remove that it should work, but like Horcrux7 pointed out, -recurse is not intended to be used like this either. So you can simply do:

ikvmc D:\fop\build*.jar -version:1.0 -out:D:\fop\fop.dll

Answer (score 1):

Which warnings do you receive? See the [ikvmc error messages](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Ikvmc_messages). For the exception you should give us the stacktrace and what you do as the exception occur. Also should you write which ikvm version do you use.

Comment: Please find a picture of the error message and command i am using at: http://uploadimage.co.uk/images/64641904662310269419.png. The version i am using is the latest from SourceForge(0.44.0.5).

Comment: EDIT: The version i am actually using is 0.45.3987 from ikvm.net

Comment: This look like a bug on a wrong use. The recurse parameter is for class files and not for jar files. Jar files can you simple add as separate parameter. See the docu at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Ikvmc

Answer (score 0):

Try [NFOP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfop/), it does not depend on IKVM.

Comment: Hi Fabio - Is NFOP still being actively developed? The last release i can find was 2008, i didn't go down the NFOP route because of this, i didn't want to use something which wasn't being supported and developed. Do you know what the status of this project is?