# convert xml file to pdf c#

Tags: c#, xml, pdf

i want to convert xml file to pdf file in c#.

this is my code.

```
private void printAllDataReceiveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        // Load the FO style sheet.
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load("bookFo.xsl");

        // Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
        xslt.Transform("books.xml", "books.fo");
    }
    private void GeneratePDF(string foFile, string pdfFile)
    {
        FileInputStream streamFO = new FileInputStream(foFile);
        InputSource src = new InputSource(streamFO);
        FileOutputStream streamOut = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
        Driver driver = new Driver(src, streamOut);
        driver.setRenderer(1);
        driver.run();
        streamOut.close();
    }
```

however, FileInputStream, InputSource and FileOutputStream shows the error

> The type or namespace name 'FileInputStream', InputSource, FIleOutputStream could not be found (are you missing a  using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is how i import things (i do not know the right terms for it)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

//add data to xml
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
//convert to pdf
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Xml.XPath;


using System.IO;
```

i have been searching through the internet and it said i should add this.

```
using org.apache.fop;
using org.apache.fop.apps;
using org.apache.fop.tools;
using org.xml.sax;
using java.io;
```

even i am using this, it saying the same error missing using directive or an assembly reference. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What third party libraries are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you probably also need the dll; I found this post with an answer marked as correct. It explains how to generate the dll: [Using ApacheFOP v1.0 in .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961476/using-apachefop-v1-0-in-net-application)

Answer (score 0):

`FileInputStream` is a java class.  `java.io` is a java namespace.  You can't use these sensibly in .NET.  You appear to be mixing platforms and this is why you're having problems.

The approximate equivalent of `FileInputStream` in .NET is probably `StreamReader`; for `FileOutputStream` use `StreamWriter`.  I'm not sure what `InputSource` is doing so I can't offer a solution there.

If you need more help, you should probably include details of which 3rd-party libraries you're using (since `Driver` isn't a standard class) and also which websites you've referred to, since adding `java.io` in a .NET app is unlikely to work in most situations...

Answer (score 0):

vjslib.dll doesn't work for .NET Framework 4.0. 
Here are the details: [msdn details](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualjsharpgeneral/thread/79d26927-ddcb-4306-afff-47152232d76c/)

If you want your application to work, change the target framework to .Net Framework 3.0 or 2.0