# XML to PDF in ASP.NET

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt

Is there a way and example code for converting xml document to pdf (also we are using xslt to create xml).? I could not find any free library or example code for it. Could you help me?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FOP.dll/ is Apache FOP cross-compiled with IKVM to .NET so you can use it to process for XSL-FO to PDF. To transform XML to XSL-FO you can use any XSLT processor available for .NET like the Microsoft XslCompiledTransform for XSLT 1 or the .NET version of Saxon 9 HE (also available on NuGet).

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSL-FO. See [Generating PDF in .NET using XSL-FO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099485/generating-pdf-in-net-using-xsl-fo).

Another way of doing it is using XSLT to transform your document to a Word or Excel and then print it to PDF with the Office API.